# POST values not pulling through on HTML form input

Tags: php, html

EDIT: Clicked post way too early on this!! Basically the values don't pull through and update the database at all but it treats it as though it is a success with no error messages.

I wonder if anyone can solve this for me.

I've got a HTML form that auto submits when a checkbox is ticked and/or unticked.

The HTML looks like this:

```
        <form action='propupdate.php' id='propupdate' method='post'>
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $userData['id'] ?>" id="ID" form="propupdate">
  <input type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="slideThree" name="check" onchange="document.getElementById('propupdate').submit()" <?php echo ($userData['prop']=='Yes' ? 'checked' : '');?> form="propupdate"/>
  <label for="slideThree"></label>
        </form>
```

When I check the hidden value it is correct, I've also tested the php which makes it auto checked or unchecked and this works. At first I though the autosubmit was missing the hidden input so I tried adding in form= into the inputs but this didn't seem to work.

propupdate.php looks like this:

```
<?php

include 'index.php';
include 'credentials.php';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//Create variables
$ID=$_POST['ID'];
$prop=$_POST['slideThree'];

$sql = "UPDATE users SET prop='$prop' WHERE ID='$ID'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header("Location:example.com");
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Any help is massively appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `<input....` that you want to be sent when you submit the form MUST have a `name` attribute. The `id` attribute is only used by the DOM and javascript

So add a name attribute to this line

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $userData['id'] ?>" name="ID" id="ID" form="propupdate">
```

and it will get sent to the PHP script

Comment: Perfect dude! Rookie error on my part, thanks for the help. I'll accept it when I can, says I have to wait another 8 minutes.